# Problem trying to make radar charts and colour two different lines in R

Tags: r, radar-chart

I am trying to make a radar chart of some data from a survey- plotting survey results (one colour line and "desired results" with a different colour. I can get the plot to work, but  I cant colour by line type (actual -v- desired). I've tried to build it with the fmsb library- the data Biosupport$Score is just the column from a dataframe that I'm interested in.

In principle it works fine, except the colouring which returns the error:

"Error in radarchart(Radar.data, seg = 9, title = "Chart", pfcol = colour.fill,  :
formal argument "pcol" matched by multiple actual arguments"

If I remove the offending line of code (see comment below) it plots- just without colouring- any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Library(fmsb)
 Radar.data.test <- data.frame(Test1=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[1], 4),
                               Test2=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[2], 4),
                               Test3=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[3], 4),
                               Test4=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[4], 4),
                               Test5=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[5], 4),
                               Test6=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[6], 4),
                               Test7=c(5,0, Biosupport$Score[7], 4),
                               Test8=c(5,0, Biosupport$Score[8], 4),
                               Test9=c(5,0,Biosupport$Score[9], 4),
                               row.names = c("max", "min", "Survey Data", "Desired result"))

   colour.fill <- c(scales::alpha("gold", 0.3),
                    scales::alpha("white", 0.1))

  colour.line <- c(scales::alpha("yellow", 0.2),
                   scales::alpha("darkgray", 0.9))

  radar.chart <- radarchart(Radar.data,
                            seg=9,
                            title =  "Chart",
                            pfcol=colour.fill,
                            pcol=colour.line, # this line is causing issues- when removed it plots
                            plwd = 3,
                            plty = 1,
                            pcol=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, spent half an hour with your script to find out you have repeated pcol variable assignment. So just remove the last line:

```
radar.chart <- radarchart(Radar.data,
                      seg = 9,
                      title =  "Chart",
                      pfcol = colour.fill,
                      pcol = colour.line,
                      plwd = 3,
                      plty = 1,
                      maxmin = TRUE)
```

I've added maxmin variable just for a completeness.

[image]